# How to sort different types of data according to their priority?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I am sorting a list of objects according to a variable stored in them. Lets name that variable "sortCriteria" 
A sample set of "sortCriteria" values for different objects :

400, 329, 529, "String1", 678, "String2", 588, "String3", "String1",  201, "String2"

So, basically there are 4 kind of values I can get in "sortCriteria" : 
1. A numeric value
2. String1
3. String2
4. String3

Now I have to sort this data in such a way that the numeric data should be given the most priority, then "String1",  then "String2" & then "String3". i.e. 
Priority of (Numeric > String1 > String2 > String3) 
Note that, in output, all those numeric values should be in sorted order.

Hence, the sorted order of sample data would be -
201, 329, 400, 529, 588, 678, "String1", "String1", "String2", "String2", "String3". 
Also, if multiple objects are having same "sortCriteria" values, their order should be retained. 
Eg. 
Let say I got 2 objects whose "sortCriteria" value is same 
Object 1 : 205,
Object 2 : 205.
Then in sorted order Object1 should come before Object2.

My current Javascript implementation of sorting specific logic looks like this :

```
function mySortRule(a, b) {
         var value1 = a[1], value2 = b[1];
         var value1Priority = getPriorityOf(value1);
         var value2Priority = getPriorityOf(value2);
         return value1Priority - value2Priority;
}
function getPriorityOf(value) {
         var priority;
         if(value!="String1" && value!="String2" && value!="String3") {
             priority = value;
         }
         else if(value == "String1") {
            priority = Number.MAX_VALUE-2;
         }
         else if(value == "String2") {
            priority = Number.MAX_VALUE-1;
         }
         else if(value == "String3") {
            priority = Number.MAX_VALUE;
         }
         return priority;
}
sortCriteriaArray.sort(mySortRule);
```

sortCriteriaArray[i] value is in this format : 
["indexOfObject", "sortCriteria"]

This solution is kind of working but it's not retaining the objects order. Also, I don't feel that this is a good approach because -
 
1. Tomorrow, let say we have to fit in some other types of strings. In that case, we will have to change these conditional statements in getPriorityOf() function.
 
2. Using "Number.MAX_VALUE" to set the priority looks hacky to me. 
Can there be any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Check for the type. if both are numeric or both are string, use regular comparison (`"String1" < "String2"` this is alphabetically sorted). else, the lowest one is the numeric one.

Comment: you can not sort objects with numbers (positive 32 bit, as indices for arrays) as key, as long as these number are not in order.

Comment: why this not help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54310041/10761855

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrange the comparison test to be lexicographical, first on the type (assigning priority indexes such as like number: 0, string: 1), then on the value in case of ties. This is clean and extensible.

To retain the order, you need to use a stable sorting algorithm such as MergeSort.

---

Alternatively, if you don't plan to add other types, proceed as follows:

- scan the list and split (stably) in a sublist with the numbers and another sublist with the strings;
- sort the sublists and concatenete them.

Comment: Yes, this one looks cleaner to me. I am gonna use this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my solution and check if it fits:

```js
// Array
const arr = [400, 329, 529, "String1", 678, "String2", 588, "String3", "String1", 201, "String2"];

// Filter methods
const isNumber  = (item) => !isNaN(item);
const checkString  = (str) => (item) => item === str;

// Sort/Config method
const sortPriority = () => {
   return [
   ...arr.filter(isNumber).sort((a, b) => a - b),
   ...arr.filter(checkString("String1")),
   ...arr.filter(checkString("String2")),
   ...arr.filter(checkString("String3")),
   ]
}

console.log(sortPriority());
```

Comment: @Cid my fault, fixed. Thx, mate

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have a small and fixed number of strings, you could build a composite sorting rule using an object as a dictionary for priorities instead of your `getPriorityOf` and then you don't have to use `MAX_VALUE`. You could take an object for the order of the given strings or a default value of zero (assuming numbers are the top priority) and then sort by numerical value.

```js
var data = [400, 329, 529, "String1", 678, "String2", 588, "String3", "String1", 201, "String2"],
    order = { String1: 1, String2: 2, String3: 3 };

data.sort((a, b) => (order[a] || 0) - (order[b] || 0) || a - b);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Unfortunately `Array.sort` is not guaranteed to be stable although often in practice it is. See also [About the stability of the algorithm used by V8 engine](https://v8.dev/blog/array-sort)

If it is not stable in your environment, you can emulate stable sort using a [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) to store the original positions.

The fact that you ask for stability implies, that you really have some objects that you want to sort by some field. I assume that field called `data`. Note that the `index` property is not used by the algorithm, it is in this example only to proof the stability of the order.

```js
var data = [{ index: 0, data: 400 }, { index: 1, data: 329 }, { index: 2, data: 529 }, { index: 3, data: "String1" }, { index: 4, data: 678 }, { index: 5, data: "String2" }, { index: 6, data: 588 }, { index: 7, data: "String3" }, { index: 8, data: "String1" }, { index: 9, data: 201 }, { index: 10, data: "String2" }],
    indices = new WeakMap(data.map((o, i) => [o, i])),
    order = { String1: 1, String2: 2, String3: 3 };

data.sort((a, b) => 
    (order[a.data] || 0) - (order[b.data] || 0) || // get priority ordering
    a.data - b.data ||                             // order by number
    indices.get(a) - indices.get(b)                // keep same values in order
);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I like this code for simplicity, but does the spec for `Array.sort` requires a stable algorithm to be used? This seems to be a thing that the OP complains about

Comment: But that's exactly one of the problems that OP is complaining about at "_Also, if multiple objects are having same "sortCriteria" values, their order should be retained._" and again "_This solution is kind of working but it's not retaining the objects order._"

Comment: the result is dependent of a stable implementation of the sorting algoritm **or** if another parameter is used for keeping the order.

Comment: So in other words do I understand correctly that this answer doesn't really cover the actual OP's problem?

Comment: As far as I read the question, the OP already has a code that works but there are two things he doesn't like: 1. the result sorting is not stable 2. the code is not future-proof. Am I right that you kind of address #2 but do not address #1 at all?

Comment: please look at section two.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187128/discussion-between-serggr-and-nina-scholz).

Answer (score 0):

```
function mySortRule(a, b) {
    function getPriorityOf(value) {
        // priority order..
        return [Boolean, Number, String, Array, Object, Function]
            .reverse().indexOf(value.constructor);
    }
    // smallest first..
    return getPriorityOf(a) == getPriorityOf(b) ?
        (a.valueOf() == b.valueOf() ?
            0 :
            (a.valueOf() > b.valueOf() ? 1 : -1)) :
        getPriorityOf(b) - getPriorityOf(a)
}
var sortCriteriaArray = 
    [400, 329, 529, "String1", 678, "String2", 588, "String3", "String1", 201, "String2"];
sortCriteriaArray.sort(mySortRule);
// -> [201, 329, 400, 529, 588, 678, "String1", "String1", "String2", "String2", "String3"]
```

(Assuming every array element is neither null or undefined)